# Factorial ANOVA for Market Research

Tags: anova

Suppose I want to see who will most likely buy ice cream from my store. Here is my plan: I group people into different categories based on sex, hair color, whether they are wearing shorts or pants, etc. watch people come in my store and take note of cost of the ice cream they buy. What would be the best test to see which group I should advertise to?

I'm thinking of doing a factorial ANOVA to test all the variables and the interaction of the variables. Is this apt or is there something better?

Another question I have is how long should I do this? What test should I use if instead of the total price of what they bought I took the total of how many people in a particular group stepped into my store?